# How to reduce a 1 year from a date which is format like "08/01/2018"?

Tags: typescript

> var date = "08/01/2018";

I need output as "08/01/2017"
How do I return the same date but 1 year earlier?

Comment: you might be interested in moment.js, it is powerful library to perform different date related functions easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the value to date and use getFullYear , setFullYear methods

```
let d  = new Date('08/01/2018');
console.log(d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear()-1));
```

[setFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
var date = "08/01/2018";
var dt = new Date(date);
console.log(new Date(dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() - 1)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
var date = new Date("08/01/2018");
date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - 1 );
console.log(date);
```